# "Incompatible types" error while compiling runtime parameter annotation using static import

Tags: java, annotations

Using the following annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Param {
    String value();
}
```

And constants class:

```
public final class ExampleConstants {
    public static final String classConstant  = "classConstant";
    public static final String methodConstant = "methodConstant";
    public static final String paramConstant  = "paramConstant";
}
```

The following class:

```
import com.example.annotations.Control;
import com.example.annotations.Param;
import com.example.annotations.Task;

import static com.example.ExampleConstants.*;

@Task(value = classConstant)
public class ExampleClass {
    @Control(methodConstant)
    public Object control(@Param(paramConstant) ExampleParam paramConstant) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Fails to compile with the error:

```
Error:(12, 34) java: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.String
  found:    com.example.ExampleParam
```

If I change the @Param annotation declaration to not use the static import, it compiles as expected:

```
public Object control(@Param(ExampleConstants.paramConstant) ExampleResult paramConstant)
```

I'm looking for clarification on the following:

- Why does the static import reference fail to compile
- Why does the compile error state the "found type" as the method parameter type
- Why does the class reference import compile
- What can I do to get the static import to work (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation that annotation values can't have static and/or wildcard imports.

The error indicates that the value is of the type `ExampleParam` - The issue here is that the method's parameter has the same name as the imported constant: `paramConstant`

In the example with the `ExampleConstants.paramConstant` the value is more specific and therefore isn't hidden any more.

Rename the parameter, so it doesn't hide the imported value any more:

```
public Object control(@Param(paramConstant) ExampleParam exampleParam)
```

Comment: Goodness, that's... I feel like I both should have realized that on my own and that I'd never have realized that.  Thanks.